# Rails: how does form_for accept a local variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Code generated by Rails 5 generator:

```
<%= form_for(post) do |f| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I am confused as to why the first line form_for(post) works. Because in this context the post in question is stored in an instance variable @post. I'd like to know what mechanism is allowing a naked `post` to work as well. I would have thought that was an undefined (or null) local variable.

Answer (score 0):

1) Its defined somewhere above in the template.

2) This view is `partial` and parent view is injecting the variable.

3) Controller injects the variable into template.

You can debug it with adding a `binding.pry` breakpoint and checking the value of the `post` variable.